# Dialogflow Integration with Twitter

Tags: twitter, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have followed the steps given for integrating with Twitter https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations but I am not able to find the server URL

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

When command `gcloud beta run deploy` is executed successfully, it will explicitly prompt in the CLI **Service URL: https://dialogflow-PLATFORM-xxxxxxxx-xx.x.run.app** and this will be the server URL.

In case you missed it in the CLI you can check it in the GCP console:

1. Open Cloud Run, it will show all available cloud run services
2. Select the recently deployed Dialogflow service
3. Click "Details" tab. This tab will contain information including the server URL
4. These fields are Region,URL, Last revision deployed
5. Copy value for URL as this is your **Service URL**.

For testing I deployed a simple helloworld app. Sample deployed service:

[image]